# Parsing error: Unexpected token const

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

I am currently setting up a meteor application and I am using eslint and babel, but I get the following error for the following code snippet:

```
const Navigation = props => (
  const classes = props.classes;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    </div>
  )
);
```

Error:

```
2:4 - Parsing error: Unexpected token const
```

I have recreated my eslint config [here](https://eslint.org/demo/#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).
My .babelrc config is the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are using the `concise body` of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and that expects the expression inside `()` and not a statement. To use a statement you need to use `block body` by using `{}` instead of `()`.

Like this:

```
const Navigation = props => {
  const classes = props.classes;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    </div>
  )
};
```

As per **[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**:

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit
>   return is attached. In a block body, you must use an explicit return
>   statement.

Answer (score 2):

**@Mayank Shukla** has the solution, but I would like to add that you could also do:

```
const Navigation = ({classes}) => (
  <div className={classes.root}>
  </div>
);
```

The `({classes})` part is called "object destructuring" and basically means that you're extracting the `classes` property from the `props` parameter that your function receives.

You could do this with any number of parameters. For example:

```
const Navigation = ({classes, children}) => (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

Take a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) for more info:

> The **destructuring assignment** syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.