# How to iterate through array that is value of key in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have JSON file like this

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "Afghanistan",
    "city": ["Eshkashem","Fayzabad","Jurm","Khandud"]
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "Italy",
    "city": ["Milano","Rome","Torino","Venezia"]
 }
```

]

and I want to iterate through array placed in the city. Idea is to have two selects, where the first select is reserved for countries and the second is reserved for cities. Whenever the user selects a country, I want to populate the second select with a list of cities. Problem is that I receive only one array of all cities for that country. Here is my code:

```js
export default class DiffCountries extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            contacts: [],
            selectedCountry: [],
            selectedCity: []
        }
    }
    
    onChangeHandler = (event) => {
      const test = CountriesData[event.target.value - 1];
        
        this.setState({
            selectedCountry: test,
            selectedCity: this.state.selectedCountry.city
        })

        console.log(this.state.selectedCity);
    }
    
    render() {
        const { contacts } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            <select name="" id="" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
                            {CountriesData.map(item => {
                                const { id, country } = item;
                                return <option key={id} value={id}>{country}</option>
                            })}
                        </select>
                        <select name="" id="">
                            {this.state.selectedCountry !== undefined ?
                                <option value="">{this.state.selectedCountry.city}</option> :
                                null
                            }
                            
                        </select>
           </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the screenshot of my problem [image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```js
const CountriesData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    country: 'Afghanistan',
    city: ['Eshkashem', 'Fayzabad', 'Jurm', 'Khandud'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: 'Italy',
    city: ['Milano', 'Rome', 'Torino', 'Venezia'],
  },
];

class DiffCountries extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedCountry: null,
    };
  }

  onChangeHandler = event => {
    const selectedCountry = CountriesData[event.target.value - 1];

    this.setState({
      selectedCountry,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedCountry } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          name="country"
          defaultValue="country"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
        >
          <option disabled value="country">
            Select country
          </option>
          {CountriesData.map(({ id, country }) => (
            <option key={id} value={id}>
              {country}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        {selectedCountry && (
          <select name="city" defaultValue="city">
            <option disabled value="city">
              Select city
            </option>
            {selectedCountry.city.map(item => (
              <option key={item} value={item}>
                {item}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DiffCountries />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the array.

```
this.state.selectedCountry.city.map((city, index) => {
    return <option value={city} key={index}>{city}</option>
})
```

Be aware, that using the index as a key is considered an [anti](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) [pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). You could use the name of the city as a key as well. E.g.:

```
this.state.selectedCountry.city.map(city => {
    return <option value={city} key={city}>{city}</option>
})
```

edit to add link to mdn docs as suggested in comments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: See the map documentation on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You have also missed `key`. Without unique key it will throw error.

Comment: As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46283426/5779083) answer, you can use normal brackets () to imply an imediate "return"

Comment: Since using the index as a key in this way is considered an anti-pattern, should that code snippet be returned to prevent anyone copy and pasting without going over the whole answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `map()` on the city array.

```
<select name = "" id = "" > {
    this.state.selectedCountry !== undefined ?
    this.state.selectedCountry.city.map((x,i) => <option value={x} key={i}>{x}</option>)
    :null
  }

</select>
```